# How to set dns on mobile network for android?

Tags: java, android, dns, 3g, 4g

Is there any way to set the dns for mobile network on android?
I've searched everywhere and only found how to set dns for wifi using wifimanager.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question.

Comment: I once created an app for the same but sadly that app didn't got live on playstore.

Comment: @GabeSechan it's related to programming, i want to do this programmatically, i've found several posts regarding this topic but with wifi not mobile network

Answer (score 1):

It may not be what you are referring to, but just in case - in a mobile network there is a DNS that is entirely separate from the public internet DNS.

Its purpose is to provide domain name resolution within the mobile networks - for GPRS roaming, networking between different operators IMS system, delivery MMS between operators etc.

Its kept completely separate, largely for security reasons, and the network operator or the GRX/IPX operator sets the DNS - IP Packet exchange (IPX) is a network connecting IP network providers and GPRS Roaming exchange (GRX) is a hub for exchanging traffic between GPRS providers.

The mobile or 3GPP DNS is not set by the mobile device or by an app on the mobile device (unless the app happens to be admin app for a member of the GRX/IPX operator team...).

As a simple example, to try to show how this DNS is actually used, an SGSN node in an operators core IP network may want to get the IP address of a GGSN node in the network that it needs to communicate with - it uses this mobile network DNS system to resolve the domain name of the GGSN. Its fairly clear why you would not want a mobile device to be able to influence this process - otherwise a rogue mobile device could change how the elements of the core network communicate with each other.